when does MCU load sram functions from flash?
I'm trying to figure out when MCU loads sram functions from flash.
I'm trying with S32K324.
I have defined a function in sram.
void __attribute__((section(".test_sram_section"))) MyFunction(void);

vscode can show the address of it, and it's in sram as expect.
However, even I put a breakpoint just after a line of ENTRY POINT and triggered there, I can still find the function in sram.
by the way, the ENTRY POINT is right where the code start I think.
//
so...when does MCU loads functions into sram from flash?

Just a quick idea: This happens when the CRT loads initialized data into RAM. Can you stop the target right at reset before any machine code executes?

What compiler and tool chain is this about? The CRT will be different depending on compiler, libs and linker used.

To see an uninitialized RAM memory where your RAM function address is, you have to inspect the RAM BEFORE the loader is called, i.e. for a microcontroller typically at the start of the reset event handler.
The entry point of your program is the point where the control is passed to AFTER that the operating system or the loader has finished its task:

so, the entry point isn't always the first piece of code executed
the entry point of a C program most of the time is the main() function, but typically the main() function isn't called immediately after reset
after reset, the reset handler routine is called, that handles the low level initialization
one of the initializations tasks (the loader) takes care of loading and initializing the program's sections
after the initialization completes, typically the program's entry point function is called

The startup code is executed immediately after reset, and typically is contained in a module with a name that recalls the startup procedure, e.g. for the NXP LPC43xx series it is named cr_startup_lpc43xx.c.
The loader, typically in a microcontroller a few lines contained in the startup code, takes care, among other things, of copying the code of your function:

from the data segment of your program image

where it is stored by the linker


to the appropriate address in the RAM memory.

In the following, a snippet, taken from the LPC43xx cr_startup_lpc43xx.c module, that handles the copy of data section from flash to the RAM:
//*****************************************************************************
// Reset entry point for your code.
// Sets up a simple runtime environment and initializes the C/C++
// library.
//
//*****************************************************************************
void ResetISR(void) {

// some other initializations here

//
// Copy the data sections from flash to SRAM.
//
unsigned int LoadAddr, ExeAddr, SectionLen;
unsigned int *SectionTableAddr;

// Load base address of Global Section Table
SectionTableAddr = &__data_section_table;

// Copy the data sections from flash to SRAM.
// ***
// *** N.B.: one of the sections copied here will be the one containing the code of your RAM function
// ***
while (SectionTableAddr < &__data_section_table_end) {
    LoadAddr = *SectionTableAddr++;
    ExeAddr = *SectionTableAddr++;
    SectionLen = *SectionTableAddr++;
    data_init(LoadAddr, ExeAddr, SectionLen);
}
// At this point, SectionTableAddr = &__bss_section_table;
// Zero fill the bss segment
while (SectionTableAddr < &__bss_section_table_end) {
    ExeAddr = *SectionTableAddr++;
    SectionLen = *SectionTableAddr++;
    bss_init(ExeAddr, SectionLen);
}

// some other stuff here

// call the entry point (main())
 main();


The S32K324 seems to have 4MB internal Program Flash, are you sure, you have to use external Flash?
Second, to load from external Flash usually is not part of the application and its startup code, because there needs to be some internal loader to configure the clock and interface, check maybe for the type of the external Flash and search at certain position for a secondary bootloader or HSM (SecureBoot) Firmware. Since this SBL can be adapted, it can then load anything from any sector of the external Flash.
